# Azure Media Services - Creating custom preset for video analysis

Tags: azure

New to Azure Media Services so working through the examples as detailed here ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/analyze-videos-tutorial-with-api

After running the AnalyzeVideos example successfully, my next steps are to create a *Transform* to output a lot less data. I'm not interested in the face tracking, mood tracking, etc etc - plus it makes the whole process take a long time.

I'm really just interested in the metadata being output from the analysis job but even after hours of searching I can not find any way to do this! Surely someone out there has this wrapped up?

The most useful thing I found on my searches was this but since it has the word *previous* in the URL I'm not hopeful

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-face-and-emotion-detection

Answer (score 0):

Well after making contact with the azure mothership the definitive answer is you can't filter the results.

Seems like a real shortcoming to me since it makes the whole *Job* take a long time but hey what do I know!